# I can't change my brightness setting on my computer

Tags: brightness

Whenever I try to change my brightness setting, it doesn't change. Please help me with this!

Comment: Please add some information to your question. How do you try to change the brightness? What computer/laptop do you have? What GPU does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install this software:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/brightness-controller/

You find in the ubuntu software center.

Comment: You saved my computer!!!